# How to implement an 'in' clause in Entity Framework?

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I have the following query

```
select distinct X.* from X
inner join Y on X.ID = Y.ID1
inner join Z on Y.ID= Z.ID2
where X.param = 1 and Z.param in (1,2)
```

So far I have the joins and the where clause on the X.param implemented but I'm struggling on the in clause of Z.param. The list of id's is supplied by a listofids of type List

```
entities.X
.Join(entities.Y, t1 => t1.ID, t2 => t2.ID1, (t1, t2) => new { X= t1, Y= t2 })
.Join(entities.Z, t => t.Y.ID, t3 => t3.ID2, (t, t3) => new { X= t.X, Y= t.Y, Z= t3 })
.Select(d => d.X).Distinct().Where(x1 => x1.param == 1)
```

Adding the following does not work

```
Any(d1 => d1.Z.param.Contains(listofids))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Removed the Any and added the 'in' clause to the 'Where' clause entities.X
    .Join(entities.Y, t1 => t1.ID, t2 => t2.ID1, (t1, t2) => new { X= t1, Y= t2 })
    .Join(entities.Z, t => t.Y.ID, t3 => t3.ID2, (t, t3) => new { X= t.X, Y= t.Y, Z= t3 })
    .Where(x1 => x1.X.param == 1 && listofids.Contains(x1.Z.param)).Select(d => d.X).Distinct()

Answer (score 2):

You need to reverse the `Contains`:

```
Any(d1 => listofids.Contains(d1.Z.param))
```

Comment: Thanks for the correct usage. But doing so know results in a compile error
Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<>'

Comment: I assume `listofids` is a `List<int>`? Is `d1.Z.param` an `int`?